# What is session and how it is maintained

Tags: asp.net, session

I know this is not a question which has code but I was asked a question about SESSION in an interview. Not session variable. Say I have same site open in 2 different tabs of my browser. In one tab i query for the search results of the hospitals in New York and in the second tab(same website) i query for the restaurants in New York. How I get the different results in 2 different tabs and how they don't get mixed up as the request is going from the same browser. Is there any session object that the browser is maintaining.? I could answer about SESSION variable in asp.net but couldn't answer hoe the above condition works. Please explain me the concept of please provide me links .

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154708/what-logically-and-physically-is-a-session

Answer (score 2):

A **session** is a semi-permanent interactive information interchange, also known as a dialogue, a conversation or a meeting, between two or more communicating devices, or between a computer and user. A session is set up or established at a certain point in time, and then torn down at some later point. An established communication session may involve more than one message in each direction. A session is typically, but not always, stateful, meaning that at least one of the communicating parts needs to save information about the session history in order to be able to communicate, as opposed to stateless communication, where the communication consists of independent requests with responses.

**session management** is the process of keeping track of a user's activity across sessions of interaction with the computer system.

**A session token** is a unique identifier that is generated and sent from a server to a client to identify the current interaction session. The client usually stores and sends the token as an HTTP cookie and/or sends it as a parameter in GET or POST queries. The reason to use session tokens is that the client only has to handle the identifier—all session data is stored on the server (usually in a database, to which the client does not have direct access) linked to that identifier. Examples of the names that some programming languages use when naming their HTTP cookie include JSESSIONID (JSP), PHPSESSID (PHP), CGISESSID (CGI), and ASPSESSIONID (ASP).

More Information :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)